# How to add categori selection option in theme option?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a category option in my wordpress theme using option tree. I am using this code in theme-option.php

```
  <?php
    $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name');
    $wp_cats = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category_list ) {
    $wp_cats[$category_list->cat_ID] = $category_list->cat_name;
    }


add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_theme_options', 1 );

function custom_theme_options() {

  $saved_settings = get_option( 'option_tree_settings', array() );


  $custom_settings = array(
    'sections'        => array(
      array(
        'id'          => 'general',
        'title'       => 'Home Page  Settings'
      )
    ),
    'settings'        => array(

      array(
        'id'          => 'Great-Product',
        'label'       => 'Great Product',
        'desc'        => 'select great Product category',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'section'     => 'general',

   'std' => 'Choose a category',
  'options' => $wp_cats
      )
    )
  );

  if ( $saved_settings !== $custom_settings ) {
    update_option( 'option_tree_settings', $custom_settings );
  }

}
 ?>
```

But it is not showing any category. Where is my fault? Please tell me.

Comment: Where is your `$wp_cats` defined ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Just need to write

```
  'type'        => 'category-select',
```

insted of

```
  'type'        => 'select',
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `$wp_cats` variable within your function, or use `global` to bring it in.

Option 1 (global variable)

```
  <?php
    $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name');
    $wp_cats = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category_list ) {
    $wp_cats[$category_list->cat_ID] = $category_list->cat_name;
    }


add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_theme_options', 1 );

function custom_theme_options() {

  global $wp_cats; /** GLOBAL!! */

  $saved_settings = get_option( 'option_tree_settings', array() );


  $custom_settings = array(
    'sections'        => array(
      array(
        'id'          => 'general',
        'title'       => 'Home Page  Settings'
      )
    ),
    'settings'        => array(

      array(
        'id'          => 'Great-Product',
        'label'       => 'Great Product',
        'desc'        => 'select great Product category',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'section'     => 'general',

   'std' => 'Choose a category',
  'options' => $wp_cats
      )
    )
  );

  if ( $saved_settings !== $custom_settings ) {
    update_option( 'option_tree_settings', $custom_settings );
  }

}
 ?>
```

Option 2 (build variable inside function)

```
  <?php

add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_theme_options', 1 );

function custom_theme_options() {

    $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&orderby=name');
    $wp_cats = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category_list ) {
    $wp_cats[$category_list->cat_ID] = $category_list->cat_name;
    }


  $saved_settings = get_option( 'option_tree_settings', array() );


  $custom_settings = array(
    'sections'        => array(
      array(
        'id'          => 'general',
        'title'       => 'Home Page  Settings'
      )
    ),
    'settings'        => array(

      array(
        'id'          => 'Great-Product',
        'label'       => 'Great Product',
        'desc'        => 'select great Product category',
        'type'        => 'select',
        'section'     => 'general',

   'std' => 'Choose a category',
  'options' => $wp_cats
      )
    )
  );

  if ( $saved_settings !== $custom_settings ) {
    update_option( 'option_tree_settings', $custom_settings );
  }

}
 ?>
```

Comment: No change. same result

Comment: Right before you use the `$wp_cats` variable (i.e. before the line starting `$custom_settings = array(...)`) why don't you put `var_dump( $wp_cats );` which will output the contents of the $wp_cats variable. If the variable is defined and included properly, there should be no issue. We know it's now included. So the problem is probably with populating that variable. (stepping through your $categories foreach() loop)